# Websphere 8.5 Application to IBM WebSphere Liberty on AWS migration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, websphere-liberty

After searching for "websphere quickstart aws" I discovered the IBM WebSphere Liberty project.

I am not confident an application built on [IBM WAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server#Version_8.5.0) 8.5 will work on this newer version.

Is there a quick assessment I can make, other than setting up a https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/ibm-websphere-liberty/ to know this old app will be forwards compatible?

Answer (score 2):

There are two tools you can do to do an analysis of your application. These are:

[IBM Transformation Advisor](http://ibm.biz/cloudta) - This tool runs as a set of docker containers and can analyse your application and will indicate how hard and how likely it will move to Liberty.

[WebSphere Binary Migration Toolkit](http://ibm.biz/WAMT4AppBinaries) - This tool is a simple jar file that will report any and all things that may be a problem. It is used by the IBM Transformation Advisor.

The binary scanner tool will flag more items than IBM Transformation Advisor because in our experience many of the items are trivial to work around and therefore are cheap and others are expensive so it promotes the harder to do things and demotes the simple things.

If you have an application deployed into traditional WebSphere both tools have the ability to perform configuration migration for the application, things like JDBC resource configuration. This is not complete but does provide a good leg up if you are unfamiliar with Liberty configuration.

Comment: Can't figure out the **binaryInputPath** requirement for the .ear I'm trying to analyze. https://s.natalian.org/2020-04-13/binaryInputPath.txt